# Why not the second class attribute overwrites the previous one. HTML

Tags: html, css

Browsers interpret the HTML and show the results as it interprets it. So why not the first class attribute gets overwritten by the second.

```
<span class ='first' class= 'second' >text</span>
```

But if I do

```
<span class ='first' class= 'second' style='color: green'>text</span>
```

all previous styling is overwritten.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXCtn/1/).

Thank you.

Comment: Because none of the two lines of code is a valid HTML part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having the same attribute twice is invalid HTML, and browsers perform error recovery.

Specifically, from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#before-attribute-name-state):

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be dropped, along with the value that gets associated with it (if any).

So the second class attribute is ignored because the start tag already has a class attribute.

(Note that you can specify multiple classes on an element since the attribute takes a space separated list: `class="first second"`)

Style attributes do not overwrite class attributes. The element will have both attributes associated with it. However, when the style sheet is applied, a style attribute rule will have a higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than a rule with a class selector, so properties specified in style attributes win the cascade.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the syntax is invalid, you can have only 1 `class` attribute inside a tag.

And as far as the over riding goes, `inline styles` has the highest precedence in CSS.

The correct way to use multiple classes is like this

```
<span class ='first second'>text</span>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXCtn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

1. a html element can only have 1 `class` (or 1 of any other type of property) so the second one will always be rejected by the browser (even if it would look like the element has 2 - effectively it will have only one)
2. the rule is that the `style` property on an element will always take the priority before style in a `class`