# jQuery .change only works on ID, and not when I try class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with some tables exported from a database, and I have a dropdown box at the top and bottom of the table where users can select how many rows to show.

When I only had one, I used ID="num", but now I use class="num" on both and it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" class="num">
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.num').change(function () {
   window.location.href = "LINK HERE/"+this.value;
});
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: you have 2 class attributes - change it to `class="form-control num"`

Comment: Put them together `class="form-control num"`

Comment: `this.value` also work like `$(this).val()`

Comment: OMG. How could I miss that! I just changed from id to class to fast. But now it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DOM element has 2 class attribute, that's invalid. Split your class with space :

```
<select class="form-control num">
```

> **class = cdata-list [CS]** 
>  This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

[W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: Thanks, I cant belive I missed that. Im a little tired..

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control num">

$(document).on('change','.num',function () {
   window.location.href = "LINK HERE/"+this.value;
});
```

Comment: Why on earth do you use event delegation to fix the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this as You were using class attribute twice:

```
class="form-control num"
```

Comment: `class` is an *attribute* name, not a *tag* name.

Answer (score 1):

Your element have 2 class attribute (and only the first will be evalueted); instead of double define `class`, set them in one attribute split by a space:

```
<select class="form-control num">
```

Having the same attribute twice is invalid HTML, and browsers perform error recovery, great explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833224/975520).

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before
>   emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name
>   must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; if there
>   is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then
>   this is a parse error and the new attribute must be dropped, along
>   with the value that gets associated with it (if any).